# Search code in azure devops projects with REST api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, azure-devops, dotnet-httpclient, azure-devops-rest-api

i am trying to search code through some project, i didnt succeed to recieve a proper response.

that what i did:

```
       public async void GetProjects()
    {
        try
        {
            var personalaccesstoken = "mypersonalPat";

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                    new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                    Convert.ToBase64String(
                        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                            string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", personalaccesstoken))));

                var httpClient = new HttpClient();

                var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
                list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("searchText", "a"));
                list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("$top", "10"));
                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(list);


                var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://almsearch.dev.azure.com/myorganization/myproject/_apis/search/codesearchresults?api-version=5.1-preview.1", content);
                var res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

in the response i got 203 status message, in the res i got this (formatted as XML):

```
Azure DevOps Services | Sign In         var __vssPageContext = {"webContext":{"user":{"id":"aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa","name":"Anonymous","email":"","uniqueName":"TEAM FOUNDATION\\Anonymous"},"host":{"id":"7d0cc8e9-39e8-4313-9ff3-23ace0f8f4cf","name":"TEAM FOUNDATION","uri":"https://spsprodweu4.vssps.visualstudio.com/","relativeUri":"/","hostType":"deployment","scheme":"https","authority":"spsprodweu4.vssps.visualstudio.com"}},"moduleLoaderConfig":{"baseUrl":"/_static/tfs/M166_20200303.4/_scripts/TFS/min/","paths":{"Profile/Scripts/Resources":"en-US","VSS/Resources":"en-US","Account/Scripts/Resources":"en-US","UserManagement/Scripts/Resources":"en-US","Authentication/Scripts/Resources":"en-US"},"map":{},"contributionPaths":{"VSS":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M166_20200303.4/_scripts/TFS/min/VSS","pathType":"default"},"VSS/Resources":{"value":"en-US","pathType":"resource"},"q":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M166_20200303.4/_scripts/TFS/min/q","pathType":"default"},"knockout":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M166_20200303.4/_scripts/TFS/min/knockout","pathType":"default"},"mousetrap":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M166_20200303.4/_scripts/TFS/min/mousetrap","pathType":"default"},"mustache":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M166_20200303.4/_scripts/TFS/min/mustache","pathType":"default"},"react":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M166_20200303.4/_scripts/TFS/min/react.15.3","pathType":"default"},"react-dom":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M166_20200303.4/_scripts/TFS/min/react-dom.15.3","pathType":"default"},"react-transition-group":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M166_20200303.4/_scripts/TFS/min/react-transition-group.15.3","pathType":"default"},"jQueryUI":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M166_20200303.4/_scripts/TFS/min/jQueryUI","pathType":"default"},"jquery":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M166_20200303.4/_scripts/TFS/min/jquery","pathType":"default"},"OfficeFabric":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M166_20200303.4/_scripts/TFS/min/OfficeFabric","pathType":"default"},"tslib":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M166_20200303.4/_scripts/TFS/min/tslib","pathType":"default"},"@uifabric":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M166_20200303.4/_scripts/TFS/min/@uifabric","pathType":"default"},"VSSUI":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M166_20200303.4/_scripts/TFS/min/VSSUI","pathType":"default"}},"shim":{"jquery":{"deps":[],"exports":"jQuery"}},"waitSeconds":30},"coreReferences":{"stylesheets":[{"url":"/_static/tfs/M166_20200303.4/_cssbundles/Default/vss-bundle-ext-core-css-vgEHbWqZ4eb0vmOdl2cWjkpPtqcsX1GJCq4DnY78oN3s=","highContrastUrl":null,"isCoreStylesheet":true}],"scripts":[{"identifier":"JQuery","url":"/_static/3rdParty/_scripts/jquery-2.2.4.min.js","fallbackUrl":null,"fallbackCondition":null,"isCoreModule":true},{"identifier":"JQueryXDomain","url":"/_static/3rdParty/_scripts/jquery.xdomainrequest.min.js","fallbackUrl":null,"fallbackCondition":null,"isCoreModule":true},{"identifier":"Promise","url":"/_static/tfs/M166_20200303.4/_scripts/TFS/min/promise.js","fallbackUrl":null,"fallbackCondition":null,"isCoreModule":true},{"identifier":"GlobalScripts","url":"/_static/tfs/M166_20200303.4/_scripts/TFS/min/global-scripts.js","fallbackUrl":null,"fallbackCondition":null,"isCoreModule":true},{"identifier":"LoaderFixes","url":"/_static/tfs/M166_20200303.4/_scripts/TFS/pre-loader-shim.min.js","fallbackUrl":null,"fallbackCondition":null,"isCoreModule":false},{"identifier":"AMDLoader","url":"/_static/3rdParty/_scripts/require.min.js","fallbackUrl":null,"fallbackCondition":null,"isCoreModule":true},{"identifier":"LoaderFixes","url":"/_static/tfs/M166_20200303.4/_scripts/TFS/post-loader-shim.min.js","fallbackUrl":null,"fallbackCondition":null,"isCoreModule":false}],"coreScriptsBundle":{"identifier":"CoreBundle","url":"/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-basejs-v9GpWWBnsWqhM23ijhK2HfAqLowTXGUqZLDRsBCZbkfY=","fallbackUrl":null,"fallbackCondition":null,"isCoreModule":true},"extensionCoreReferences":{"identifier":"CoreBundle","url":"/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-ext-core-vjMBLvR7Lq0Z_oS-OpRMsP9FOHhkdmDXf0mCbsK5c0RI=","fallbackUrl":null,"fallbackCondition":null,"isCoreModule":true}},"webAccessConfiguration":{"isHosted":true,"paths":{"rootPath":"/","staticContentRootPath":"/","staticContentVersion":"M166_20200303.4","resourcesPath":"/_static/tfs/M166_20200303.4/_content/","staticRootTfs":"/_static/tfs/M166_20200303.4/","cdnFallbackStaticRootTfs":"/_static/tfs/M166_20200303.4/","staticRoot3rdParty":"/_static/3rdParty/"},"api":{"webApiVersion":"1","areaPrefix":"_","controllerPrefix":""},"mailSettings":{"enabled":false},"registryItems":{}},"microsoftAjaxConfig":{"cultureInfo":{"name":"en-US","numberFormat":{"CurrencyDecimalDigits":2,"CurrencyDecimalSeparator":".","IsReadOnly":true,"CurrencyGroupSizes":[3],"NumberGroupSizes":[3],"PercentGroupSizes":[3],"CurrencyGroupSeparator":",","CurrencySymbol":"$","NaNSymbol":"NaN","CurrencyNegativePattern":0,"NumberNegativePattern":1,"PercentPositivePattern":1,"PercentNegativePattern":1,"NegativeInfinitySymbol":"-∞","NegativeSign":"-","NumberDecimalDigits":2,"NumberDecimalSeparator":".","NumberGroupSeparator":",","CurrencyPositivePattern":0,"PositiveInfinitySymbol":"∞","PositiveSign":"+","PercentDecimalDigits":2,"PercentDecimalSeparator":".","PercentGroupSeparator":",","PercentSymbol":"%","PerMilleSymbol":"‰","NativeDigits":["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"],"DigitSubstitution":1},"dateTimeFormat":{"AMDesignator":"AM","Calendar":{"MinSupportedDateTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","MaxSupportedDateTime":"9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999","AlgorithmType":1,"CalendarType":1,"Eras":[1],"TwoDigitYearMax":2029,"IsReadOnly":true},"DateSeparator":"/","FirstDayOfWeek":0,"CalendarWeekRule":0,"FullDateTimePattern":"dddd, MMMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss tt","LongDatePattern":"dddd, MMMM d, yyyy","LongTimePattern":"h:mm:ss tt","MonthDayPattern":"MMMM d","PMDesignator":"PM","RFC1123Pattern":"ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'","ShortDatePattern":"M/d/yyyy","ShortTimePattern":"h:mm tt","SortableDateTimePattern":"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss","TimeSeparator":":","UniversalSortableDateTimePattern":"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'","YearMonthPattern":"MMMM yyyy","AbbreviatedDayNames":["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"],"ShortestDayNames":["Su","Mo","Tu","We","Th","Fr","Sa"],"DayNames":["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"],"AbbreviatedMonthNames":["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec",""],"MonthNames":["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December",""],"IsReadOnly":true,"NativeCalendarName":"Gregorian Calendar","AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames":["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec",""],"MonthGenitiveNames":["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December",""]},"numberShortForm":{"QuantitySymbols":["K","M","B"],"NumberGroupSize":1000,"ThousandSymbol":"K"},"eras":null}},"timeZonesConfiguration":{},"featureAvailability":{"featureStates":{"VisualStudio.Services.Contribution.EnableOnPremUnsecureBrowsers":false,"VisualStudio.Service.WebPlatform.ClientErrorReporting":false,"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Gallery.Client.UseCdnAssetUri":false,"VisualStudio.Services.WebAccess.SubresourceIntegrity":false,"VisualStudio.Services.IdentityPicker.ReactProfileCard":true}},"appInsightsConfiguration":{"enabled":false,"instrumentationKey":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","insightsScriptUrl":null},"diagnostics":{"sessionId":"24ec3e5b-2a51-44d0-8738-32e2f2c48c12","activityId":"24ec3e5b-2a51-44d0-8738-32e2f2c48c12","bundlingEnabled":true,"webPlatformVersion":"M166","serviceVersion":"Dev18.M166.1 (build: AzureDevOps_M166_20200320.5)"},"navigation":{"topMostLevel":"deployment","area":"","currentController":"Signin","currentAction":"Index","routeId":"LegacyWebAccessRoute","routeValues":{"controller":"Signin","action":"Index"}},"globalization":{"explicitTheme":"","theme":"Default","culture":"en-US","timezoneOffset":0,"timeZoneId":"UTC"},"serviceInstanceId":"951917ac-a960-4999-8464-e3f0aa25b381","hubsContext":{},"serviceLocations":{"locations":{"951917ac-a960-4999-8464-e3f0aa25b381":{"Application":"https://spsprodweu4.vssps.visualstudio.com/","Deployment":"https://spsprodweu4.vssps.visualstudio.com/"}}}}; var __cultureInfo = __vssPageContext.microsoftAjaxConfig.cultureInfo;
```

hope someone can tell me the proper way to send the post request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below script:

```
            try
            {
                var personalaccesstoken = "{token}";

                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {

                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                        new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                        Convert.ToBase64String(
                            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                                string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", personalaccesstoken))));

                    var httpClient = new HttpClient();

                    var newcontent = new StringContent("{\"searchText\":\"gradle\",\"$top\":33}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("https://almsearch.dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/search/codesearchresults?api-version=5.1-preview.1", newcontent))
                    {
                        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Is there maybe a typescript version of this code somewhere?